# JSON multilevel Object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to extract sum of frequencies from a deeply nested JSON object.

```
{ "Baltimore":{
    "health": {
      "hospital": {
        "data": {"frequency": 3, "relevance": 0.7845, "sentiment": "Mixed"},
        "metadata": {
          "article1": {"author": "Tom Jones", "title": "Current Rises in Health Insurance Policies in Baltimore", "timestamp": "26-FEB-1987 15:01:01.79"},
          "article2": {"author": "Bob Jenkins", "title": "Obamacare in Hospitals", "timestamp": "06-SEP-2011 16:32:34.73"},
          "article3": {"author": "Tom Jones", "title": "Rises in Hospital Fees", "timestamp": "31-DEC-1991 01:45:59.66"}
        } 
      } 
    },
    "crime": {
      "assault": {
        "data": {"frequency": 12, "relevance": 0.9045, "sentiment": "Negative"},
        "metadata": {
          "article1": {"author": "", "title": "Another shooting in Baltimore", "timestamp": "26-FEB-1987 15:01:01.79"},
          "article2": {"author": "Anderson Silva", "title": "Street Crime up in cities", "timestamp": "06-SEP-2011 16:32:34.73"},
          "article3": {"author": "John Jones", "title": "Rise in assaults in Baltimore", "timestamp": "31-DEC-1991 01:45:59.66"}
        } 
      },
      "robbery": {
        "data": {"frequency": 15, "relevance": 0.553, "sentiment": "Positive"},
        "metadata": {
          "article1": {"author": "Rob", "title": "Robbery of Museum in Baltimore", "timestamp": "26-FEB-1987 15:01:01.79"},
          "article2": {"author": "Anderson Silva", "title": "Man held at gunpoint for wallet", "timestamp": "06-SEP-2011 16:32:34.73"},
          "article3": {"author": "John Jenkins", "title": "Increase in robbery frequency in MD", "timestamp": "31-DEC-1991 01:45:59.66"}
        } 
      }       
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the count of frequency for every second level object (considering Baltimore as first level). So in this case output should be Baltimore.health=3 and Baltimore.crime = 27. Third level objects are not fixed in number. For example, in health there can be more additional objects like "Safety" or something, each having there own frequency.
I am trying to do like this:

```
function value(obj){
  var i=0;
  for (var x in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
      i = i+x.frequency;
    }
  } 
  return i;
}
```

But when I pass an object to 'Obj', x is not iterating on objects.

Comment: What object is it that you are trying to pass to the function?

Comment: There is no frequency on second level objects.  It's much deeper than that.

Comment: Inside the for loop you need _obj[x].frequency_ - x is a string with the property name, it's not the property value. (Though even that isn't going to work because _frequency_ is nested more deeply.)

Comment: @Guffa I was passing Baltimore.health

Answer (score 0):

As nnnnnn pointed out, `x` is the name of the property, so you need to use bracket syntax to access the property. The object in the property doesn't have a `frequency` property, that's inside the object in its `data` property:

```
function value(obj) {
  var i=0;
  for (var x in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      i += obj[x].data.frequency;
    }
  } 
  return i;
}
```